# how to sort an array of structs by a date field?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct

I have an array of Items, each one is a structure with an expiration date field (a string based on the pattern: dd/mm/yyyy).
I sorted the array with maxsort algorithm but came across a promblem when several Items had the same expiration date.
According to the exercise`s instructions, in the above-mentioned scenario the order between the Items should be by the order of their appearance in the presorted array.

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct _item {
    char item_name[ITEM_NAME_LENGTH];
    char department[DEPARTMENT_NAME_LENGTH];
    char expiration_date[EXPIRATION_DATE_STRING_LENGTH];
    double price;
    int available;
}Item;
```

```
void swap(Item* xp, Item* yp)
{
    Item temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
```

```
int Index_of_max(Item* store, int len)
{
    int i, i_max = 0, curr_year, year, curr_month, month, curr_day, day;
    for (i = 1; i <= len - 1; i++)
    {
        year = (store[i].expiration_date[9] - '0') + ((store[i].expiration_date[8] - '0') * 10) + ((store[i].expiration_date[7] - '0') * 100) + ((store[i].expiration_date[6] - '0') * 1000);
        curr_year = (store[i_max].expiration_date[9] - '0') + ((store[i_max].expiration_date[8] - '0') * 10) + ((store[i_max].expiration_date[7] - '0') * 100) + ((store[i_max].expiration_date[6] - '0') * 1000);
        if (year > curr_year)
        {
            i_max = i;
        }
        if (year < curr_year)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (year == curr_year)
        {
            month = (store[i].expiration_date[4] - '0') + ((store[i].expiration_date[3] - '0') * 10);
            curr_month = (store[i_max].expiration_date[4] - '0') + ((store[i_max].expiration_date[3] - '0') * 10);
            if (month > curr_month)
            {
                i_max = i;
            }
            if (month < curr_month)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (month == curr_month)
            {
                day = (store[i].expiration_date[1] - '0') + ((store[i].expiration_date[0] - '0') * 10);
                curr_day = (store[i_max].expiration_date[1] - '0') + ((store[i_max].expiration_date[0] - '0') * 10);
                if (day > curr_day)
                {
                    i_max = i;
                }
                if (day < curr_day)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return i_max;
}
```

```
void Sort_By_Date(Item* store, int *len)
{
    Item* temp_store = (Item*)malloc(*(len) * sizeof * store);
    int length, i;
    for (length = *(len); length > 1; --length)
    {
        int i_max = Index_of_max(store, length);
        swap(&store[length - 1], &store[i_max]);
    }
    free(temp_store);
}
```

```
case 2:
        {
            Sort_By_Date(store, len);
            printf("You chose to sort the inventory by the expiration date.\n");
            Actions_Menu();
            continue;
        }
```

I thought about making a copy of the array before the sorting and then deal with the duplication problem, but couldn`t come up with the right solution.

thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all show how the date is represented.

Comment: It sounds as if you're looking for a [stable sorting algorithm](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/stable-sorting-algorithms).

Comment: the date is in the format i mentioned: for example - "02/06/2022"

Comment: @larsks thats correct, but i can`t seem to implement any of those algorithms in my code.